# How would bounded context help when doing microservices?

Tags: microservices, domain-driven-design

So at first I though we would have 1:1 relation between a service and bounded context. I though strategic design in DDD would help decomposing **Domain** into several services and reduce a lot of complexity, but I was wrong. Actually you can have many services inside of bounded context not just one. So how would bounded context help when doing microservices since you still have those messy services but just inside of a bounded context with specific ubiquitous language.

Comment: Any supporting reference for your statement that  "you can have many services inside of bounded context not just one"?

Comment: @Salil maybe watch this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xjx4Zkh0NDU at the 2:50

Comment: @Salil and also this one microservices.io/patterns/decomposition/decompose-by-subdomain.html, so microservies.io said that we can decompose by subdomain and you can have multiple subdomain in a bounded context which means that a bounded context would contain one or more services.